# Adobe Flex layer is not displayed, but can zoom to it

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex, flash-builder

I am using Adobe Flex to develop a widget to allow the user to turn on/off 2 layers separately. The strange thing is only 1 layer can be displayed on the map when the layer is turned on, the other layer does not appear when turned on (but can still zoom to the layer). I cannot figure out what happens. The difference of the 2 layers is that the layer not appearing is joined to a database table. Will that affect it?

I am using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 and ArcGIS API for Flex 3.6.

Any ideas on it?